# How to get the length of a Path in java?

Tags: java, path

How do you get the length of a Path? Am I missing something here? Strangely enough, int length() nor any similar method is implemented in the Path class. Example: for the path

```
C:\foo\bar\anotherfolder\subfolder
```

the method would return 4.

Comment: I'd call that the "depth", since it's the depth in the directory tree.

Comment: Why doesn't `C:` count towards the total?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Path.getNameCount()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getNameCount()):

> Returns the number of name elements in the path.

Answer (score 2):

you can use count total number of backslash in the string which will give you same answer Like this

StringTokenizer stOR = new StringTokenizer("C:\foo\bar\anotherfolder\subfolder", "\");

If you are using windows system then you need to append extra backslash for each. Otherwise your string will give compile time error **Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \ )**

int orCount = stOR.countTokens()-1;

System.out.println(orCount);